# Replace all except first row in a multi index

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas and have loaded some data into a dataframe.  What I would like to do is replace the scenario frequency column in my data for all but the first value in each group.

My data looks like this:

```
ExplosionID  FireWater  FireID    Scenario Frequency
111          0          213       4.209055e-15
                        214       4.209055e-15
                        215       4.209055e-15
                        217       4.209055e-15
                        219       4.209055e-15
                        220       4.209055e-15
112          0          232       8.388742e-16
                        233       8.388742e-16
                        234       8.388742e-16
                        235       8.388742e-16
                        237       8.388742e-16
                        239       8.388742e-16
                        240       8.388742e-16
```

I would like to replace all but the first values in scenario frequency column with 0, so that I end up with this:

```
ExplosionID  FireWater  FireID    Scenario Frequency
111          0          213       4.209055e-15
                        214       0
                        215       0
                        217       0
                        219       0
                        220       0
112          0          232       8.388742e-16
                        233       0
                        234       0
                        235       0
                        237       0
                        239       0
                        240       0
```

The first three columns (`ExplosionI`, `FireWater`, `FireID`) are the indexes in a multi-index.

I've defined a function:

```
#function to replace all but first value in group with 0
def replace_all_except_first(group):
    group.iloc[1:] = 0
    return group
```

and have tried the following:

```
data_to_sum = HL_df_subset.groupby(level=0).apply(replace_all_except_first)
```

where `HL_df_subset` is my dataframe.  However, this places all values with 0.

I'm new to python and i know i'm completely misunderstanding how groupby works, but i've been trying all sorts and can't get it to work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

- ***`cumcount`***: to find the ordering.  create a boolean series where not equal to `0`.  This means, not the first row
- ***`mask`***: takes true values and masks the relevant parts of the dataframe.  In this case, it makes everywhwere the cumcount isn't zero a `np.nan`.
- ***`fillna`***: take those `np.nan` and fill them with zero

---

```
HL_df_subset.mask(HL_df_subset.groupby(level=0).cumcount().ne(0)).fillna(0)
```

---

consider `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(A=np.arange(100, 116)),
    pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
        [list('ab'), list('xy'), [1, 2, 3, 4]]))
df

         A
a x 1  100
    2  101
    3  102
    4  103
  y 1  104
    2  105
    3  106
    4  107
b x 1  108
    2  109
    3  110
    4  111
  y 1  112
    2  113
    3  114
    4  115
```

---

```
df.mask(df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).cumcount().ne(0)).fillna(0)

           A
a x 1  100.0
    2    0.0
    3    0.0
    4    0.0
  y 1  104.0
    2    0.0
    3    0.0
    4    0.0
b x 1  108.0
    2    0.0
    3    0.0
    4    0.0
  y 1  112.0
    2    0.0
    3    0.0
    4    0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I can confirm it works!  What does .groupby(level=[0, 1]) do exactly?  Does level 0 refer to the index containing (a, b) and level 1 refers to the index containing (x,y)?

Comment: Also, if I had other columns in the dataset, e.g. in your example say I had column B, what would I have to do to ensure the mask is only applied to column A - i.e. so that column B is kept as is?

Comment: [0, 1] refers to the first and second level of the index.

Comment: @Jimothous df.A = df.A.mask(df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).cumcount().ne(0)).fillna(0)